# Looking for an App to manage Finder Tags

Tags: applications, high-sierra, finder-tag, third-party

I am looking for an user friendly App to manage the Finder tags, multiple file, intelligent tagging and so on.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ironic Software](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/) has several Apps which can do that, f.e. '[Yep](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/yep/)' and '[Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/)'. Take a look at their descriptions, both are Sierra-compatible.